# how to get json array object in textview help me

Tags: android

my code does not get json objet in "entree" array help me please
 my code does not shoewinside json array "entree":{  values check my code is correctly acces???  my code not go inside after this line  JSONArray school = data.getJSONArray("entree");

```
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);

                JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);
                message = json2.getString("message");
                status = json2.getString("status");
                if (status.equals("1")) {


                JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

                JSONArray school = data.getJSONArray("entree");


                JSONObject jsonOrder = (JSONObject) school.get(0);

                txt1.setText(jsonOrder.getString("id"));
                txt2.setText(jsonOrder.getString("name"));
                txt3.setText(jsonOrder.getString("description"));

                String url1 = jsonOrder.getString("image");

                imgLoader.DisplayImage(url1, img1);






        {
  "status":1,
   "message":"",
   "data":
   {
 "entree":{
  "id":32,
 "name":"Cheese Burger",
    "description":"Lorem ipsum.",
   "image":"http:\/\/198.57.208.46\/~school\/images\/android\/cheese-burger.png",
  "contains":
   [
    {
   "name":"Cheese",
   "image":"http:\/\/198.57.208.46\/~school\/images\/android\/cheese1.png"
 }
,
 {
  "name":"Tomato",
 "image":"http:\/\/198.57.208.46\/~school\/images\/android\/tomato.png"
}
 ,
 {
 "name":"Bread",
 "image":"http:\/\/198.57.208.46\/~school\/images\/android\/bread.png"
}
 ]
 ,
  "nutritions":
 {
 "Calories":"150",
  "Carbohidrates":"16g"}
 }
  }
 }
```

Comment: `entree` is an object not an array.

You should replace `JSONArray school = data.getJSONArray("entree");` with `JSONObject school = data.getJSONObject("entree");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi entree is an object not an array use getjsonobject("entree");

Comment: JSONObject schoolobject  = data.getJSONObject("entree");

Comment: how to get this values  then?

"entree":{
  "id":32,
 "name":"Cheese Burger",
    "description":"Lorem ipsum.",
   "image":"

Comment: name = entreeobject.getsring("name")
id = enteeobject.getint("id") like that

Comment: you can refer jsontree.com to know which is object which is array which is string..
just paste your json string in second yellow box and click parse json